# View in RecyclerView does not match parent width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a **horizontal recyclerview**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvRecommendedVendors"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llRecommendedVendors"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:background="@color/dark_blue"
        />
```

It has an item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibRecommendedCoverPhoto"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_cover_image"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Both controls' widths are set to match_parent however, the imagebutton won't "match" its parent's width.

I logged the width:

**recyclerView Height: 338**
**recyclerView Width: 480**

This is from the recyclerview method onCreateViewHolder:

```
  @Override
    public RecommendedVendorsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup vg, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(vg.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recommended_list, vg, false);
```

I logged the view's height and width:

**View v Height: 338**
**View v Width: 327**

I tried setting the width programmatically:

```
@Override
    public RecommendedVendorsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup vg, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(vg.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recommended_list, vg, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params= (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
        params.width=480;
        v.setLayoutParams(params);

        return vh;
    }
```

**View v Height: 338** 
**View v Width: 480**

It works but I don't want to resize the view everytime.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I encounter something similar like this one, but don't know how to resolve it :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't revisited this problem yet. I remember using a viewpager. Please upvote the question so more people will be interested in answering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView is very crappy when it comes to properly positioning it and/or its child views.
Try

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    // match_parent won't work for RecyclerView (sigh)
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = parent.getWidth();
    lp.height = parent.getHeight();
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

which basically replaces match_parent for both height & width within the child view.
For your particular case you would only set the width then.

Answer (score 1):

I use **androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter** for adapter,
I have the same problem: my **view_holder_item has setted match_parent properties of width**, but it **appears on screen like wrap_content**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
...
```

Just make your **onCreateViewHolder set LayoutParams to your ViewHolder View**. In my case it looks like

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StopWatchViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = StopWatchItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val lp = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        binding.root.layoutParams = lp
        return StopWatchViewHolder(binding)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

i think the problem is from

> vg.getContext()

Let change to applicationContext or pass context to CustomAdapter

Comment: I tried it, it's not working. Also in the android documentation it shows that you should use vg.getContext. Check it out: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Thanks, anyway!